# How to "rate-limit" a PCollection in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing

I have what seems to be a common problem but I can't figure out what the Beam recommended solution is.

I have a stream of raw events and I'm looking for two separate events to fulfill a condition within a sliding window (of 60 minutes) for it to "trigger" an alert.

That is easy enough to do with `SlidingWindows`, however the problem is due to its sliding nature, I effectively get that alert potentially in multiple windows. How do I ultimately get a PCollection that outputs such alert only once (within a certain timeframe/cooldown duration)?

I first thought that the recent stateful processing feature would be my solution, but then realized that it only works within a window. So do side-inputs. So it seems to me that I need a way of breaking the windows and treat the alert "firings" in one (possible Session-)window. But the docs don't mention any kind of way to effectively reassign elements to new windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with a re-windowing strategy, similar as @Kenn suggested.

So I have alerts from a sliding windowed collection that I re-window into session windows

```
.apply(Window.remerge())            
.apply(Window.into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardHours(1))))
```

In that windowed collection, I can just do a `groupBy` and thus get all `Alerts` of a session, within which I can apply my cooldown logic of only emitting an alert every hour.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting application!

Just to summarize:

- It sounds like "sliding window" for your use case means continuously sliding. You could choose a minimum granularity but it isn't necessarily natural.
- Each set of events you are interested in should only produce one output.

There are a couple ways to approach this, depending on the rest of your application.

One way is to leave your data in the global window and use state. You will have to manage lateness yourself - dropping elements that are too late, accounting for data coming out of order, etc, and generally keeping your state bounded.

Another way is to use sliding windows with a `Combine` or state (basically, what you have already tried) and then re-windowing the alerts and de-duplicating. You could use fixed windows for this since the alert should have a deterministic timestamp; the end of the window will govern when state is automatically collected so that is handy.

Comment: Kenn, thank you for your response. I actually forgot to update this question with my findings. In regards to your suggestion:

> One way is to leave your data in the global window and use state.

That is indeed an option, but wouldn't I miss the point of using beam then?

Comment: > Another way is to use sliding windows with a Combine or state (basically, what you have already tried) and then re-windowing the alerts and de-duplicating.

I effectively went with this solution. However, fixed windows do not work since I could have an alert in the later half of the window, thus resetting the "cooldown" so any early alert in the next window should not get triggered.